# 2D "game" development: coordinates for game logic and for drawing

Tags: c++, 2d, coordinates, sfml, game-development

I've finished implementing game logic, now it's time to visualize it - I've chosen SFML for this purpose. However, I'm in a mess: **how can I avoid hard-coding coordinates of game objects** to make the whole system:

- resizable;
- comfortably movable in terms of its visual parts and systems of ones;
- self-adaptable for any sensible screen size?

Besides, I wonder **which methods are used in "real" games and other apps**. The best solution I've come up with is:

- `class Screen_promille` operated by game logic for storing `x` and `y` as `int` promilles of the used part of the screen (e.g. `{500, 500}` is the center point while `{999, 999}` is the right bottom one);
- `sf::Vector2<float> convert_to_pixels(Screen_promille const)` function for getting the actual position on the screen (probably right before drawing); or maybe make `Screen_promille::operator sf::Vector2<float>()` instead;
- `sf::Rect<float> const used_screen` for the implementation of the latter.

**Should it ^ be wise enough**?

P. S.:

- I'm not using any game engines: I want the current project done without them;
- I know about SFML typedefs. :) I left them aside for wider audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, it's not worth the hassle when you consider all of the issues you might run into down the line. It's much easier to just hardcode the coordinates.

The best solution to the concerns you raised is implementing a [letterbox view](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source:-Letterbox-effect-using-a-view). A letterbox view should allow you to resize your game comfortably without any visual distortions and it should self-adapt for any screen size.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the letterbox view is about placing the whole picture in the center of the window? That's what I'm intuitively doing right now. :) What about my `Screen_promille` "invention" - can I expect it to scale well with the letterbox view?

Comment: @passing_through The purpose of the letterbox view is to prevent game objects from appearing stretched when the user resizes the window. For example, if you have a square and you resize the window vertically then the square will be stretched vertically into a rectangle which you obviously don't want. This stretching effect occurs whenever the aspect ratio (ratio of width to height) of the new resized image isn't identical to the aspect ratio of the original image; in other words, the square is no longer a square because it hasn't been stretched by the same amount horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @passing_through In regards to your "invention", it depends on what kind of game you're trying to create. For example, it would make more sense to hard-code the coordinates for a platformer game for instance versus an idle clicker where the game is more "interface-based" if that makes sense.